# Cannot generate a Nuget package (.nupkg file)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a class library project and I can build and rebuild the project properly. When I try to create a pack for my project, I get an error saying :

```
The file 'C:\Users\Test\..\Debug\netstandard2.0\MyApi\MyApi.dll' to be packed was not found on the disk.
```

My .csproj file looks like this :

```
    <Project Sdk = "Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
     <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
       <OutDir>$(DIstributionDir)</OutDir>
       <ProductReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>true</ProductReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>
     </PropertyGroup>
  </Project>
```

I have the nuget.exe of version v6.2.0

Comment: check you console's path

Answer (score 0):

According to your description I make some test to reproduce the problem.

You can add `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` inside the `<PropertyGroup>` tag in your .csproj file.
[image]
Here is the test result:
[image]

Comment: I tried that, I still see the same problem.

Comment: @user19011893 You can change <GeneratePackageOnBuild> to true and use "dotnet build" in the command line. This method can also create a nuget package successfully.

Comment: I tried it, still the same thing.

Comment: Can you share more information such as screenshots of command line errors? Remember to hide your private information.